# Как убрать вложенность в массиве?

Tags: javascript, массивы, алгоритм

Допустим у нас есть массив:

```
['a', 12, [19, 'c', 0], [[[45]]], [0], []]
```

нужно написать функцию (на JS), при передачи в которую данного массива получится:

```
['a', 12, 19, 'c', 0, 45, 0]
```

У меня есть идея что надо с помощью рекурсии проходить по каждому элементу массива и с помощью `typeof` и `length` проверять каждый элемент, и если это массив вызывать для него рекурсию.

Но полноценный алгоритм не получается написать, буду благодарен.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Можно просто воспользоваться методом [flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat):

```js
const array = ["a", 12, [19, "c", 0], [[[45]]], [0], []]

const flatted = array.flat(3)

console.log(flatted)
// ["a", 12, 19, "c", 0, 45, 0]
```

Comment: Можно расширить для любой вложенности.
`let array = ["a", 12, [19, "c", 0], [[[[45]]]], [[[[[146]]]]], [0], []];
let depth = 0;
while (array.some(item => Array.isArray(item))) array = array.flat(depth++);
console.log(array);`

Comment: @renich или просто `array.flat(Infinity)`